# How do I access BIOS on my MacBook Pro (13 Inch - middle 2012)?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, startup, hardware, firmware

On many Intel based computers, pressing the delete key shortly after powering on the computer, allows you to enter BIOS (or equivalent to it). How do I enter BIOS or equivalent on my MacBook Pro?

Please note it is traditional Intel Mainboard i5, without EFI.

Comment: Macs don't have a BIOS, never did.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish (aka once you could access it, what do you want to do)?

Comment: Tetsujin - Did Apple modify the Intel board to remove BIOS?  Also, I when remove the Maintosh HD and replace it with an MBR HD, I can boot Lunux and Windows. Without BIOS and without an EFI partition, how can booting an MBR HD work?

Comment: patrix - One of the reasons I joined this forum is that answers were promised without further questions (unless you need to clarify the question). If you can answer the question please do so, if not please do not reply.

Comment: No Apple did not modify the Intel board they build their own./ So what are you trying to do you have taken a false premise and we need to go back to what you were doing before that.

Comment: Thanks for editing - this question still might be closed since you are basically asking a yes/no question. Does bios exist? If you re-read the comments here, everyone is trying to find out what you want bios for. We're assuming you can search the Internet to learn bios isn't loaded on a Mac, (but if that's your only question - you and everyone else has that answer)

Answer (score 6):

The closest equivalent is holding option at start. That runs the firmware that allows you to select network boot or external or internal bootable OS.

There is no open firmware anymore where you can enter commands, so you can just reset NVRAM or let the option boot read the current NVRAM settings. Anything you would set in bios, you can write to the non volatile ram from any OS X booted OS and then those variables and settings are applied next boot.

There is no bios and no concept of a user navigable hierarchy of settings to adjust before any OS loads to Apple hardware. Most of what you might do “in BIOS” isn't possible.

Comment: when I remove the Maintosh HD and replace it with an MBR HD, I can boot Lunux and Windows. Without BIOS and without an EFI partition, how can booting an MBR HD work?

Comment: @G.Davis EFI includes backwards compatibility with MBR.

Comment: @IronCraftMan - Where is EFI, when no GPT HDD is in the MacBook?

Comment: @G.Davis It's on a chip on the motherboard. The EFI partition on disks is just a place to put EFI updates.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Thank you very much, your explaination makes sense. I guess there id no user interface (similar to the BIOS interface) to EFI on the mother board chip.

Comment: @G.Davis nope. Apple locks the EFI down to only being able to choose your boot device.